# N2 CMS: Implementing Owin with OpenId connect authentication method. (FAILED)

Tags: content-management-system, openid-connect, owin, n2cms, n2

Implementing Owin with OpenId connect authentication method within existing N2 CMS system. Before was using "FORMS" authentication. Forms authentication disabled.

OpenId connect is working without problems. I am able to login trough central login page and redirect back, but when I am trying to access page with CMS context it is crashing.

See error screen: [image]

My feeling it is not able to read CMS roles.

Is N2 CMS is using HttpContext or HttpContext.Cashe?
How does it managing those roles?
Can we use multiple authentication methods and will I be able to redirect to central login page?
Do you have any suggestions?